# Show country from drop-down in edit form Laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, laravel

I'am trying to show a certian Country from a dropdown list when a user clicks on a certian ID to edit a form.

This is how my edit.blade.php form field looks like:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="country">Country:</label>
  <select id="country" name="country" class="form-control">
      @foreach(App\Http\Utilities\Country::all() as $country)
          <option value="{{ Request::old('country') ? : $flyers->country }} ">{{ Request::old('country') ? : $flyers->country }}</option>
      @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
```

This is the result I get.
[image: Dropdown Picture]

It works, BUT, when u click on the drop down it just repeats That one country that is selected over and over again until it reaches the bottom of the list.

[image: Dropdown with countries repeating]

*@foreach(App\Http\Utilitites\Country::all() as $country is coming from my countries array I made in my folder. It takes the array and lists all the countries.*

Is there a way that it can show my edited form field country, and show the other countries as well without repeating that one selected country over and over again?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="country">Country:</label>
  <select id="country" name="country" class="form-control">
    @foreach(App\Http\Utilities\Country::all() as $country)
      <option value="{{ $country }}" {{ $flyers->country == $country ? "selected" : "" }}>{{ $country }}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
 </div>
```

On this way if one of your values equals the requested value, it gets `selected`

Comment: Hackerman beat me by 30 seconds to finishing my answer. He's right. You aren't actually referencing the object created by the loop. You only reference the current/old object. So the value and text of each option needs to be changed to reference the loop's object

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project-flyer\local\resources\views\flyer\edit.blade.php)                                                                    This is the error message I got

Comment: Just for testing, can you please paste the output of: `var_dump($country)`

Comment: string(8) "Zimbabwe"            lol Thats not the country i put into the DB

Comment: well it shows the countries properly now, but when i go to click edit from, it just reverts to the default country.

Comment: Edited...again...can you post the result of `var_dump( Request::old('country'));`

Comment: I get a NULL reponse

Comment: @David, i'm glad to help :)

Comment: If the answer was helpfull, do not forget to mark it as correct :)